# How to perform SCD Typ1 on FlatFile Target in informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud

I have one Requirement. My Source and Target both are Flat Files. In Target 100 records are already present. from source I'm getting 100 records out of these 100 records 50 records has to be insert and 50 records has to be updated on target. so total record count should be 150 in target

Comment: So what specific issue are you facing? This is not a free consultancy service where someone will build a solution for you from scratch

Answer (score 0):

Flat files do not support updates. You can do a lookup to check if the data is already there and decide not to insert a given row.

Please rework the question, show what you tried and what issue are you facing. I'll be glad to help.